My screen shakes and shows double characters now
0
I am using a Dell inspiron 3501 with the following spec:
Resolution: 1920x1080
11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7 (8) @ 4.200GHz
intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
31812MiB
The challenge is that the screen keeps shaking vertically.
Before now, it will shake, and after sometime, it will become clear until I shutdown and start again or the screen sleeps.
Now, it doesn't shake. It just stays in the state of showing the characters in a double format vertically. That way I see the characters as if they are two with one a little lower than the other.
I have taken it to technicians and my screen has been replaced twice with the fault returning back after a period of about two months.
Please what could be the issue?

Try an external display.
If an external display doesn't showcase issues, then it's likely a bad cable or connector inside your laptop. If the display replacements included replacing the ribbon cable that connects your display to the iGPU, then it's probably the motherboard connector. If it's not simply a poor or dirty connection, repairing the connector will probably mean replacing the whole motherboard.
If an external display has issues, you probably have a faulty iGPU, which would require replacing the CPU.
